# Solving 'a = b ln [ max (11, b) ]' for b

Tags: math, max, approximation, natural-logarithm

Given:

```
a = b ln [ max (11, b) ]
```

If `a` is known, how can one compute `b`? (Do I need to use an iterative approximation method?)

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "iteration"? Which algorithm are you using (there are many that use iteration)?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: The question is clear, how one can obtain b, whether an iteration technique is required or not at all. "Which algorithm I'm using" -- I think you are just asking again my question. That's why I was asking, which iteration I needs (whether I need or not, previously I don't know)

Comment: I don't know why people voted down. Guys, I think my question is totally clear, how b can be calculated. Previously, I wrote, which iteration one requires. If you guys think, that one does not need iteration for this problem, just answer like that and let me know how it is. I just assumed previously that one needs iteration for this problem. If you think that this is an useful question, just leave this page.

Answer (score 2):

If `a / ln(11) <= 11`, then this is your solution and you don't need any iteration.
Otherwise solve `b * ln(b) - a = 0` e.g. with Newton-Raphson.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik. It is helpful. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graph of your function, where we have x and y rather than b and a.

[image]

Note that there is a "corner" at the point (11, 11 ln(11)). This is because your function can be re-written as:

```
a = b ln 11 if b <= 11
    b ln b  if b > 11
```

(I wish I could MathJax here as in some other StackExchange sites!)

Note that [the solution to the second version](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+a%3D+b+*+ln(b)+for+a+%3E+0) is `b = exp(W(a))` where `W()` is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Many programming languages have packages that implement the Lambert W function. In Python, for example, the common `scipy` package [calls it `lambertw()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.lambertw.html).

So a full solution in Python, after importing the `lambertw` function from the scipy module and `exp` and `log` (equivalent to ln) from the math module, is

```
b = (a / log(11) if a <= 11 * log(11)
        else exp(lambertw(a)))
```

This is easier than reinventing the wheel. Note that scipy's `lambertw` function uses continued fractions to get an approximate value then uses one or two rounds of the Newton-Raphson method to get a final result. This is faster than using only Newton-Raphson.